# Pull - using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create an object where a user can click and drag to have the effect of a pull motion. Any idea how I would do that with jQuery? Pulling down a container that is hidden off the screen. Would I use drag?

Answer (score 0):

If sounds like you're trying to replicate something similar to this:

- http://lab.oneiros.ru/jquery/sidebar/

Otherwise, yeah, I would use a div that extended off the screen and use drag and drop to "pull" things in.

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery UI there is a Draggable library that you can use.
http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

But the "off screen" part might be a hang-up.  Not sure what you mean by "off screen".

Comment: I would have some type of tab that would always be on the screen, but the panel it self will be off.

Comment: There is a JQuery UI Tab control.  Does that do what you want?